# Pass Table Name as Parameter to Dapper

Tags: dapper

Is it possible to pass in the **table name** as a parameter to a Dapper Query command?  I'm not looking for a SQL table defined function or a SQL table variable.  I want to define the table name within C# and pass it to Dapper.  Here's my code, that when executed, returns an error of `Must declare the table variable "@TableName"`

```
var foo = conn.Query("SELECT * FROM @TableName WHERE Id = @Id", new { TableName = "MyTable", Id = 123 });
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SQL does not support parameterized table names, and dapper is a very very thin wrapper over SQL - so: no.

You could, however, use string.format:

```
string sql = string.Format("... from [{0}] ...", table name);
```

Note that even with the [/] this has an inherent SQL injection risk.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I appreciate the input and I am currently doing as you suggest with the string.format.  I also realize the injection risk, but this is for an internal script controlled by us with no chance for unknown inputs.

Comment: from c#6 you can use string interpolation: $"select * from {tablename} where id = @Id" and then use parameters for everything else. Doesn't address the sql injection risk however.

Comment: If you replace the whitespaces  ``string sql = string.Format("... from [{0}] ...", tableName.replace(" ",""));``` is not vulnerable to sql injection right ?

Comment: @love2code that does nothing re SQL injection, and object/schema/etc names are allowed to have spaces in them.

Comment: @MarcGravell Assuming that a malicious user is trying to inject this sql to delete the employee table in an input instead of the real data table, e.g.: ```post; drop table employees;``` this without spaces will be just ```post;droptableemployees;``` and that won't work, it will result in an error from the sql engine running. In my case my data tables do not have spaces on them so that's why i mentioned it, because it might work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You could check to see if the table exists first to protect from Sql injection:

```
string tableNameExistsCheck = "SELECT count(1) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName";

if (c.QuerySingle<int>(tableNameExistsCheck, new { tableName }) == 1)
{
    string sql = string.Format("... from [{0}] ...", tableName);
    var result = c.Query(sql);                    
}
```

Comment: I really like this approach. It's a little more overhead to run, but if you need to dynamically insert the table name, this can really help mitigate SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

For internal, generic scripts, we use the TableNameMapper to build the sql:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(int id)
{
    string tableName = Dapper.Contrib.Extensions.SqlMapperExtensions.TableNameMapper(typeof(T));
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        int affectedRows = await conn.ExecuteAsync($"delete from {tableName} where id=@id", new { id });
        return affectedRows > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply querying the table by id you can use the Dapper.Contrib package.

Add a Table attribute to the type and a Key attribute to the Id column and then use the Get(dynamic id) extension method on the Connection.

This way you do not need to write dynamic queries.

```
[Table("cardtype-orders")]
public class CardTypeOrder 
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
 
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CardTypeOrderRepository: GenericRepository<CardTypeOrder>
{
}

public abstract class GenericRepository<T>
{
   public T Get(object id)
   {
       using (var connection = GetConnection())
       {
           return connection.Get<T>(id);
       }
   }
}
```